# Error in Connection String

Tags: string, connection

My connection string is :

error in connection string in my site

my database is in app_data

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="t1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|/t1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;User ID=UserName;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
        <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>    
  </system.web>
```

please help . my site is : seifoury.com

Comment: Connection string is a very generic concept with many possible formats depending on the context. You should give more background about the language / framework you are using and tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for every permutation possible. My guess is the section  `|DataDirectory|/t1.mdf` should be `|DataDirectory|t1.mdf`.

Could also be that you stipulate a Trusted Connection without a domain on your username. 
`Data Source=myServerAddress;...User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;`

Answer (score 0):

my connection is :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="t1" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\t1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Error Is :

```
Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.
```

Comment: remove Integrated Security=True;

Comment: This "answer" should be added as part of the **question** (there should be an **edit** button below the question, below the tags and above the author and editor area and the comment area),

Comment: @DotNetDreamer, your comment might be better as an answer